# Changing value for listview clicked item programatically

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView populated from a remote database.
This is the code for the OnPostExecute method:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        {


            progressBarSubject.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //CumplesListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if(temasHomeList != null)
            {
                ListAdapterClassTemasHome adapter = new ListAdapterClassTemasHome(temasHomeList, context);

                TemasListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                TemasListView.setClickable(true);
                TemasListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                        String  nombre_tema = temasHomeList.get(position).nombre_tema  ;
                        String  materia = temasHomeList.get(position).materia  ;
                        String  id_tema = temasHomeList.get(position).id_tema  ;
                        String  tema_seleccionado = temasHomeList.get(position).seleccionado  ;



                        mPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MIEXAMEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPref.edit();


                        String num_examen = randomString(8);

                        editor.putString("id_tema",id_tema);




                        editor.apply();

                        // SendData();

                       // InicioFragment firstFragment = new InicioFragment();
                       // ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                       //         .replace(R.id.frame, firstFragment).commit();



                    }
                });




            }
        }
```

As you may see, I am using the clicked item position to get the values for further implementation in the code.
Now I need to change the value of the position for the field:
**temasHomeList.get(position).seleccionado**
and then notify the changes to the adapter to refresh the ListView with the new value.
Is it possible?

Comment: take a quick look on this http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-notifydatasetchanged.html @mvasco

Comment: Yes. Just perform notifyDataSetChanged() it will work fine after changing the values as you are changing/referring to same instance of list.

Comment: @PrasannaAnbu, I need to know how to change the received value with another, and then set this value prior to perform notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @RamzyHassan, prior to perform notifyDataSetChanged(), I need to change the value received from the database

Comment: you have the values you got from database stored in any data structure which you pass to you adapter then you can easily get an item in specific position then updating its values after that notifiydatasetchanged() @mvasco

Comment: @RamzyHassan, yes, but this is what I don't know how to do. I get the value as:      String  tema_seleccionado = temasHomeList.get(position).seleccionado ; but how can I change this value and set this new value as  temasHomeList.get(position).seleccionado?

Comment: you can easily do it by temasHomeList.get(position).seleccionado = you new value and it works @mvasco

Comment: @RamzyHassan, I will try it, thank you. I thought it exists a set method...

Comment: @RamzyHassan, it works, thank you. Easy solution. Would you mind to put this as answer to my question?

Comment: welcome I put it as answer @mvasco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Just need to Get the old value from your List by Position Then Updating it. and **notifyDataSetChanged** like the blew code

```
temasHomeList.get(position).seleccionado = [your_new_value];
```